# how to control power within a triangle automatically

Tags: logic-gates, parallel, series

I have two mains powered extract fans with sensor operated controllers.
I need to add a third extract fan that will run if either or both of the other two are on.
How do I wire this so to prevent backfeeds from one of the existing fans to the other?

as requested:
[image]

( plug should be exchanged for word socket,  plug socket )

EDIT:   so   extractor 1 and two are to control extract heat,  a sensor plug that has a hot and cold socket is how I turn each one on.   When heat is above 23 degrees, it auto turns power onto the socket, and extractor starts working, until heat in down to the desirable temp < 23 degrees.

I was going to wire from power input on each extractor, to forward on voltage to a plug socket,   when this socket has power,  this in turn will power the third extractor.

both extractor 1 and two should be able to send power to socket at same time without any issue, and the extractor 3, will only draw what it needs.

But when  extractor 1 is on, and extractor 3 is off.   How do I stop the power from the socket, going down and powering extractor 2.

This would be undesirable as i would be extracting when i dont want to from room number 2.

Hope that makes things a bit clearer

Comment: Can you try it with a picture or block diagram?

Comment: just refine your logic of inputs and outputs. 3 inputs 3 outs with combinations to do L and/or R XOR top.  with voltage and current.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Dave, but your question is hard work. (1) I suspect that triangles are irrelevant. (2) If the bottom two are controlled independently by a controller then you can't wire them in parallel. (3) Fans don't forward voltage so this bit is technically nonsensical as is "runaway towards the top". (4) Since you're a programmer, can you create a truth table of what you want showing under what conditions each fan should turn on?

Comment: @winny added pic, will also update my post   thanks

Comment: @Dave, we need to establish some basics here. Do you know how to wire a plug, a switch and a light bulb to make a working light?

Comment: @Transistor Yeah sure,  I wire LED panels etc.   but this is all automated.   power from center plug, would power the extractor 2,  if extractor one is sending power up to the socket.   This socket is always on ( I.E  the socket is to make for easy change, moving etc of the third extractor.  as I can just unplug it,  but still have the wiring done

Comment: I also know that technically,  the extractor is not forwarding voltage.   I just meant in terms of more series than pararrel

Comment: You're on an engineering site, though, so you need to be accurate with your terminology.

Comment: why is that,   I answer stack questions all the time,  from people that dont know the right terminology.  I also mod, edit and add to post if need be to correct the terminology if needed.

Comment: did you say what voltage and currents are  on each line?  but if low voltage DC, all you need are 2 diodes ( Diode OR logic to top )  Extractors come in many sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are asking is this.

- I have two mains powered extract fans with sensor operated controllers.
- I need to add a third extract fan that will run if either or both of the other two are on.
- How can I wire this to operate without back feeding the existing fans?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fovsnW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. RLY1 and RLY2 monitor the operation of FAN1 and FAN2. The relay contacts are wired in parallel so that either will turn on FAN3.*

- You need to check that the fans are not variable speed type but just ON/OFF and are mains powered rather than low-voltage DC.
- The relay coils should be rated at 230 V AC for UK mains.
- The contacts need to be rated to carry the expected FAN3 motor current.

Comment: yep, correct, will update post

Comment: You should start applying your excellent boiling down skills on certain people’s answers too here. :-)

Comment: :-)   @winny  Yep soon changed from original did that haha

Comment: yeah they are not brilliant fans,  it is just on and off, 230 AC uk socket.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is with two relays, one connected across each fan (coil across fan motor).

Connect the two N.O. contacts in parallel to have the functionality you are asking for. Use that to switch power to the 3rd fan.

Relay coils have to match the fan motor in voltage, type of current (AC or DC)
and the relay contacts have to match the 3rd fan in switching capability.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fevmNy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks your right, this is what i was after.   much appreciated